# Why does my NuGet Gallery return 500 from nuget push?

Tags: nuget

I set up the new NuGet Gallery on a web server (under IIS 7.0) where I work. The site itself is set up and runs fine. We are able to register accounts, confirm email addresses, and even upload a new package through the site itself.

Our automated build scripts need to be able to push newly built NuGet packages to the gallery. When I use NuGet's push command:

```
nuget.exe push build\nuget\BaconAndEggs.1.0.0.1.nupkg 1451002a-8c63-4174-b7ed-73dd3e7bcdf0 -Source http://somenearbyserver/
```

I get the following result:

```
Pushing BaconAndEggs 1.0.0.1 to 'http://somenearbyserver/'...
Failed to process request. 'Internal Server Error'.
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error..
```

The website is able to upload a new package just fine, but command line isn't. If I try the push command with fiddler running, it observes two consecutive requests while executing the push command. One appears to be touching the site to make sure it's there, while the second is the actual push command.

```
Request 1: GET http://somenearbyserver/ 200 OK
Request 2: PUT http://somenearbyserver/api/v2/package/ 500 Internal Server Error
```

The content of the PUT request is correct, it contains the API key and the payload. Looking on the web server, there are no errors in the event viewer and elmah doesn't catch anything.

Fiddler shows this as the response to the PUT:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 18 Jan 2012 20:21:08 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 1208

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>500 - Internal server error.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>
  <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using `NuGet Version: 1.6.21205.9031` from the command line.

What could the problem be?

**EDIT**: After enabling detailed error pages on the api folder in the site, I get this with the 500 response described above:

```
Server Error in Application "NUGET"

Internet Information Services 7.0

Error Summary
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

Detailed Error Information
Module = LiveStreamingHandler
Notification = MapRequestHandler
Handler = WebDAV

Error Code = 0x80070585
Requested URL = http://somenearbyserver:80/api/v2/package/
Physical Path = M:\path\to\nuget-gallery\api\v2\package\
Logon Method = Anonymous
Logon User = Anonymous
```

There's also some help text included, suggestions based on verifying permissions and such, but as far as I can tell there's nothing wrong with the permissions.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I fixed this issue by changing the permissions for the IIS user. I added write permissions to `IIS_IUSRS`.

Right click the site in `IIS > edit permissions > security`

From there you add the user or group and give them write permissions.

Comment: +1. Note that the group name is `IIS_IUSRS` (with an extra `i`).

Comment: there is no "edit permissions" when right clicking a site

Comment: You should add write permission for the app pool user, `IIS APPPOOL\MyAppPoolName`. Notice three P's in a row. Substitute the name of your app pool for MyAppPoolName.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was an old local nuget server. The message I found in the logs:

> The schema version of 'YourLib' is incompatible with version
>   'someVersion.a.b' of NuGet. Please upgrade NuGet to the latest version
>   from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=213942.

In my case, I downgraded nuget (downloaded an older nuget.exe) and re-created the package. The push now works. I didn't want to disturb the process elsewhere and I needed a quick solution but of course that depends on the scenario one has. In the long run I will update nuget.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're referring to the new gallery: https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery

Can you try hitting /elmah.axd from an admin account and see if you get more info about the error?

Comment: Yeah, I'm referring to the new gallery. I checked to see if Elmah was recording anything, and it turned up nothing. I even checked in the app's folder for the error xml files, and there's nothing.

Comment: I'd try setting a break point in begin request, to see whether manages code is being hit at all. If not then it could be an IIS configuration issue.

Comment: I ran the project on my local dev machine and tried using NuGet.exe to push a package locally, and it worked just fine. I think it's definitely an IIS configuration issue. Any thoughts on what's misconfigured?

Comment: Do other requests to the gallery work (e.g the feed or the UI)? Can you try running fiddler to see what the good/bad requests look like?

Comment: I can get the command line to list packages in the feed, and the gallery website itself works fine. In fiddler I can see all of the good requests and responses, but get the 500s on the push. Once I changed the api folder in the site to return detailed errors, I started getting a bit more error information. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: I suggest starting a discussion on http://nuget.codeplex.com/ and pointing to here. Maybe someone else there will have an idea.

Comment: Brilliant! For me elmah told me I hadn't given the IIS user permission to the App_Data folder.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not mentioned, here was my scenario:
I was able to push (and retrieve) most packages without any problems. But, one package kept causing a 404 error when I attempted to push it. Several sources online indicated that I should add a mime-type for .nupkg, however all this accomplished (regardless of the mime type) was to turn the error into a 500 internal server error.

It turns out the package in question was a little larger than normal, and IIS caps the default request limit at 30MB, [causing the nuget server to return this obscure error](http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/283771). Changing the setting `system.webServer.security.requestFiltering.requestLimits.maxAllowedContentLength` to something bigger resolved it for me (after I removed the mime type I had added).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go to the IIS host server an open up the eventvwr, you should be able to tell exactly why the error happened.
look in Windows log / Application

In my case it was because of full disk. The message looks like this:

```
Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/4/ROOT-1-131895206439239270 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: E:\NuGet.Server\src\NuGet.Server\ 
    Machine name: CM 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 1876 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: IOException 
    Exception message: **There is not enough space on the disk.**
...
...
```